# Windows notifications when hibernation fails

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hibernation

I'm coding using C++ with WinAPIs, and to hibernate the computer I use the following call:

```
SetSuspendState(TRUE, NULL, FALSE);
```

But what happens is that if the computer has larger RAM array installed the hibernation fails.

So I was wondering, does Windows send any notifications if hibernation fails? And if not, how to tell if my request to hibernate failed?

Comment: You use `NULL` for the second parameter (`FALSE` would technically be more correct, as it's a `BOOLEAN`). Is there a chance that an application could block the operation, but the function still returns `TRUE` from that?

Comment: Looks like there's no direct way to detect hibernation until Windows 8.  But I suppose you could idle-loop and watch the system time.  If the time suddenly jumps forwards, you've successfully hibernated (and resumed!) and if this hasn't happened within a minute or so the request probably failed.

Comment: You could also check on the system in question whether Windows writes anything to the event log when hibernation fails.  If so, your application could monitor the event log for the relevant entry.

Comment: Thank you, fellas. I use NULL for the second parameter because it is not used since Vista. @HarryJohnston how would you do it in Windows 8? Also your system time watching approach is pretty cool. My only concern is in case of system time change or a daylight saving adjustment. What about that? In any way, this seems like an answer. Do you want to post it separately and I'll mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's no direct way to detect hibernation [***CORRECTION: I was wrong about this.  See Fowl's answer.]*** until Windows 8 (see [PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769080%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). But I suppose you could idle-loop and watch the system time. If the time suddenly jumps forwards, you've successfully hibernated (and resumed!) and if this hasn't happened within a minute or so the request probably failed.  I think you can use the [GetTickCount64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which is insensitive to system time changes but apparently includes a bias for time spent sleeping.  If this doesn't work, use [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but also watch for [WM_TIMECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages.

You could also check on the system in question whether Windows writes anything to the event log when hibernation fails. If so, your application could monitor the event log for the relevant entry.  This would be a more reliable approach.

Comment: is there really no way? .NET has http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx

Comment: Which uses the WM_POWERBROADCAST message, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373248%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Fowl: you should post that as an answer.  (I'll edit mine as well.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: first off I'm looking for a native C++ solution and not a .NET one. The .NET event is just a mirror copy of the underlying kernel event that is broadcast to native code as the WM_POWERBROADCAST message. So there's nothing new there. So going back to my question -- I'm looking to find out when a hibernation/sleep fails and so far I couldn't find a way of knowing it on either version of Windows. It's true that the SetSuspendState API can return false but it not always does ... I accepted your reply because it proposed an alternative approach...

Comment: Surely you don't receive a PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND event if hibernation failed?

Answer (score 1):

Register for ([RegisterPowerSettingNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), then listen for [WM_POWERBROADCAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373248%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and then interrogate the event log to get more detail.

There's a bit of messing around if you want to handle multiple OS versions, but it's doable.

Comment: Thanks, but "interrogate the event log to get more detail" sounds like a nice suggestion for an IT tech for over-the-phone support, but is a moot point to implement in an automated code...

Comment: You can interrogate the event log from an application.  Search for OpenEventLog in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... maybe I'm missing the point here, but according to the docs it should return FALSE if it failed. Does it still return TRUE in your case?

Comment: It seems like it does. What happens in Windows is that the process begins and then simply quits and I see the desktop again...